# How to use Document Outline if i create component programmaticlly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have MainForm parent mdi window which conatan `Menu`, `ToolBar` and `StatusStrip` created from designer in Visual Studio.

In that `MainForm` am showing child forms which content was created programmaticly (panels, textboxes, labels, grids etc...)

I have problem when i create `DataGridView` and set `Dock.Top, Dock.Fill` my grid is hidden behind parent toolbar. 
I can't use `Document Outline` on programmaticlly created controls.
I try to use `BringToFront` but again i have the some problem.

**To understand better check my screenhsot.**

```
private void InitializeDefaultObjects()
    {
        /// SPLIT CONTAINER  

        _splitContainer = new SplitContainer()
        {
            SplitterDistance = 270,
            Panel1MinSize = 270,
            Margin = new Padding(15, 15, 15, 15),
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            BackColor = Color.Gainsboro,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
            SplitterWidth = 4,
            FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel1,
            RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No,
            IsSplitterFixed = false,
            Panel1Collapsed = false,
        };
        _splitContainer.Panel1.Padding = new Padding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        _splitContainer.BringToFront();

        this.Controls.Add(this._splitContainer);

        /// TOOLSTRIP IN SPLIT CONTAINER 1
        /// This toolstrip is  merged with parent tolstrip

        _toolStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
        _toolStrip.Height = 100;
        _toolStrip.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        _toolStrip.Visible = false;
        _toolStrip.SendToBack();
        _toolStrip.BringToFront();


        // Toolstrip title
        _toolStripTitleLabel = new ToolStripLabel()
        {
            Text = this.Text,
            Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Left,
            Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
            Image = this.ToolStripTitleImage,
            ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, 
            ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.SizeToFit

        };
        // separatar
        ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator = new ToolStripSeparator() { Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right };

        // Close button
        ToolStripButton closeToolStripButton = new ToolStripButton()
        {
            Text = "Zatvori",
            Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right,
            Image = DFMSoftware.Core.Properties.Resource.Close_icon,
            TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText
        };

        // Close button event
        closeToolStripButton.Click += new EventHandler(closeToolStripButton_Click);

        _toolStrip.Items.Add(_toolStripTitleLabel);
        _toolStrip.Items.Add(closeToolStripButton);
        _toolStrip.Items.Add(toolStripSeparator);

        // add toolstripe to splitpanel
         this._splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(_toolStrip);

        // datagridview  
        _dataGridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        _dataGridView.Dock = Dock.Fill;


        // add grid to splitpanel 2
        _splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(_dataGridView);


    }
```

Here in code you can see.
1. I create SplitContainer and set BringToFront() and set Dock.Fill
2. In SplitContainer in Panel2 i add DataGridView with Dock.Fill and again is behind parent.

Am not shure how to slove this does anyone know? THanks

Screensho1[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: If your control is trying to fill the MDI space, why use MDI?  You don't have any space for MDI child forms to appear.

Comment: Am not shure to uderstand what you tell me?  Am using MDI becouse i want to all my child forms to be opened in one window.

Comment: Are we looking at the code of an MDI child form?  MDI is old technology — it doesn't like it when you set the BorderStyle to none.

Comment: `BringToFront()` gives a *lower* priority. `SendToBack()` the highest. The Control *sent to back* determines the layout of other controls with lower priority, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469851/7444103). As a general rule, then it depends on the containers' specific layout.

Comment: @LarsTech what is better than MDI? I have `BaseForm` abstract class where i all my child forms inherent that class and all have border none.

Comment: Get rid of the MDI code and just use a panel as the container on the main form.  You can keep your child forms, just turn `TopLevel = false;` on them to turn them into UserControls, essentially.

Comment: So i need to remove MDI and in parent to create one panel where i will show all my childs with `Controls.Add()` ?

Comment: Based on your screen shot, yes.  It doesn't look like you have a need to show multiple child forms at once.