# Dock order respected at design time, but not always at runtime

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I'm facing a weird and erratic issue in a WinForms project.
In a user control I have a toolbar (3rd party control) and an a subclassed RichTextBox.

The toolbar has `dock=top`, while the RTB has `dock=fill`.
I used "bring to front" on the RTB to avoid Toolbox overlapping RTB.

At design time everything is fine, both in control design and in forms where the control is used:

[image]

[image]

At runtime I experience an erratic behaviour: the control is always rendered fine as long as I place it on the form without touching any property.

If I change some property value (for example, I have a ShowFont property that I can set to false to hide fonts dropdown, both at design time and at runtime) it sometimes gets screwed and from that moment **at runtime** the bar overlaps the RTB:

[image]

This is strange because there is no code in the control that adds/removes subcontrols, thus altering their order.

Comment: Note that, when docking Controls, the z-order works the other way around. The Control with the lower z-order (set with `SendToBack()`) has priority (e.g., see the notes here: [How can I keep a Status Bar from covering my RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469851/7444103)) -- Use nested containers to separate your Controls (ToolStrips / MenuStrips / StatusStrips included). A docked TableLayoutPanel as container may also work.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this problem is caused by `dock=fill`.

I don't know why your `bring to front` fails.

You can try to open the Designer.cs file of the corresponding form and find the statement that adds controls to the form at the end of the InitializeComponent method, such as:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.RTB);
this.Controls.Add(this.toolbar);
```

Change the order to:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.toolbar);
this.Controls.Add(this.RTB);
```

If it still doesn't work, I suggest you try using `anchor`.

Comment: Thank you Jiale Xue, I already checked designer code. It seems to be ok, controls are in the right order there.

Comment: According to your description, it is indeed caused by the dock.
Did you try something like [tableppanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to separate them so they definitely don't overlap.

Comment: Do you have time to check the relevant information? Has the problem been resolved so far?