# Dock left below top Dock controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is this possible?

Basically I have a header style control that I have dock to the top. At runtime on a button click I want to be able to initialize and dock a new control on the left, but upon docking it pushes my header over.

I've tried SetChildIndex and experimented with various Z values to no avail.

Basically looking for:

```
              top Control
_____________________________________________
         |
         |
         |
left     |
control  |
         |
         |
         |
```

But I'm getting:

```
_____________________________________________
         |
         |           top Control
         |___________________________________
         |
         |
         |
left     |
control  |
         |
         |
         |
```

Comment: Have you tried `.BringToFront()` (on the new control? Or `.SendToBack()` (on the exiting)?

Comment: Yeah -- it hides the header (as in just buries it without moving it) rather than spawning below it.  ```.SendToBack()``` is the behvaiour described above.

Comment: Read the notes here: [Auto-resize multiple Forms rendered on Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476266/7444103) and here: [How can I keep a Status Bar from covering my RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469851/7444103)--`SendToBack()` is used on the Control that needs **higher** priority when docking